# Number of roots of a polynomial over a commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

For an univariate polynomial over a field, the number of roots is bounded by the degree of the polynomial.

> If f(x) is a polynomial over a commutative ring R containing a field F and $\deg f=d$ is it possible to determine a bound for the number of roots of f(x) in F?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F$ be a field and $R= \prod_{i \in I}F$ for some infinite set $I$, then $R$ contains infinitely many idempotents, that is, roots of the polynomial $x^2-x$.

Comment: I've thought the OP has asked about the number of roots in $F$.